# How to make random function calls using Android?

Tags: android, function, random

I am developing Android LBS application. I would like to make function calls  randomly through my application.

I have the following code.

```
public class DialANumber extends Activity {
  EditText mEditText_number = null;
  LinearLayout mLinearLayout_no_button = null;
  Button mButton_dial = null;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLinearLayout_no_button = new LinearLayout(this);

    mEditText_number = new EditText(this);
    mEditText_number.setText("5551222");
    mLinearLayout_no_button.addView(mEditText_number);

    mButton_dial = new Button(this);
    mButton_dial.setText("Dial!");
    mLinearLayout_no_button.addView(mButton_dial);
    mButton_dial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        performDial();
      }
    });

    setContentView(mLinearLayout_no_button);
  }

  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
      performDial();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void performDial(){
    if(mEditText_number!=null){
      try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + mEditText_number.getText())));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }//if
  }
}
```

I would like to call the `performDial()` method randomly.

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "random calls". Do you want to telephone random people, do you want to execute random code, do you want to call specific functions at random times? What do you have, show some code, how is your code-structure, what is your design... help us help you :)

Comment: Actually  i  want  to  call a   specific functions  randomly.

Comment: Randomly in time? Put a random length delay between calls, in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm still not sure I understand your question fully, you could do something like this:

```
  double rand = Math.random();
  if( rand < 0.2 )
      firstFunction();
  else if( rand < 0.4 )
      secondFunction();
  else if( rand < 0.6 )
      thirdFunction();
  else if( rand < 0.8 )
      fourthFunction();
  else
      fifthFunction();
```

(`Math.random()` generates a random double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0).